# Count Occurrence of Specific Word in the Textarea (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to write a simple JavaScript that Counts the **number of times** a word ( or a set of characters) that are typed into **input** field appear in the **textarea** field.

Example: Imagine someone pastes a long paragraph into textarea, and wants to see how many times does the word "dog" or phrase "dog on the leash" appears in the text.

Condition:

1. The match should be **case sensitive** 'Dog' and 'dog' are not the same thing
2. The match should **consider spaces** 'dog' and 'dog ' are not the same thing.

> ```
> <textarea id="txtarea" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
>
> <input type="text" id="input" cols="15" rows="1"></input>
> ```

Could someone please shed some light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var temp = "This is a dog, Dog.";
console.log((temp.match(/dog/) || []).length);
```